# Tracking changes to ORM-based objects in a database

Tags: python, orm, peewee

I have a bunch of objects that are being stored in a sqlite database using peewee ORM. What is a good pattern to store all the changes done to the objects.

One model I can think of is to use an auto-incremented ID for the objects and every time a change is made, create a new copy. Is there a better or more automatic way of doing this? Is there a pattern I can look at?

I am not opposed to using another ORM if it offers this functionality.

Answer (score 1):

The only fool-proof way to do this is by using database triggers. The downside is that there is more complexity.

For example, one approach would be, whenever a model is saved (i.e. save() is called) you would take care to ensure the previous data is persisted / changes logged.

The problems with an approach like this is if you do any kind of bulk modify operation (e.g. UPDATE...WHERE, DELETE...WHERE) which could affect more than one row, Peewee may not have visibility into what changes.

If you're literally talking about tracking "all" the changes, the only way to do this is to use triggers.

If, on the other hand, you want to track changes to a subset of fields that only change in specific ways, you can possibly handle that in the model layer (by overriding save() or whatever).

You might also be interested in the `signals` extension, which can execute callbacks whenever models are saved/deleted: http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/playhouse.html#signals